# strictTemplates causing weird issues

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application and want to add `strictTemplate` checking, but there are some odd issues.

I have a component:

```html
<app-export-form
    exportType="booking"
></app-export-form>
```

In the component I defined the input:

```js
@Input() exportType: ExportType;
```

And `ExportType` is an enum:

```js
export enum ExportType {
    RECEIPT = 'receipt',
    CREDITCARD = 'creditcard',
    BOOKING = 'booking',
}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

> 72:3 - error TS2322: Type '"booking"' is not assignable to type 'ExportType'.

`booking` is a string that's defined in the `ExportType` enum. What's causing the error here?

Using Angular 10 btw.

Comment: Well, to me it looks like the compiler is right. Try adding a public property on the component that renders `app-export-form` like the following `public ExportType = ExportType;` (where the right hand side of the `=` is your imported enum symbol). This allows you to go in the template and write this: `exportType="ExportType.BOOKING"`. This should clear out the error for you.

Comment: Example of @OctavianMărculescu's answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhmzv4?file=src/example.enum.ts

Comment: So the type annotation makes it so that only enums are accepted? Kinda makes sense :) ps, in your code you didn't add the `[ ... ]` brackets around the `exportType` but I think you have to, otherwise you just pass the string `ExportType.BOOKING` right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I missed the brackets. You need them in order for this to work